# Append a string to the end of an element attribute using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an element:

```
<select id="row" />
```

I want to append a string to the end of the id attribute, like this:

```
<select id="row_1" />
```

The jQuery I am using to achieve this is (from within an `each`):

```
$(this).attr('id',$(this).attr('id')+'_'+row_count);
```

This looks ugly as sin, and whilst it works I want to know if there is a simpler solution. In this example, the ID prefix (e.g. row) is never constant, so I can't just do `'row_'+row_count`.

Cheers!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't forget that extending jQuery is super easy:

```
$.fn.appendAttr = function(attrName, suffix) {
    this.attr(attrName, function(i, val) {
        return val + suffix;
    });
    return this;
};
```

And then everywhere else you want to do this:

```
$('p').appendAttr('id', 'i_like_turtles');
```

Comment: Would get a good speed boost with: `this.attr(attrName, function(i, val) { return val + suffix; });` if doing a large number of elements

Comment: Nick, could you explain how this proveds a speed increase? Cheers! :)

Comment: @ILMV - It's not accessing the attribute collection twice, it uses a reference to grab and set quickly.

Comment: Thanks Nick, that was my original concern actually that it was accessing it twice. Many thanks :)

Comment: @Nick, i don't know that accessing an attribute would cause a significant slowdown, but you're right: using the callback function is better, since the original code I posted wouldn't work for sets very well. I'll edit now.

Comment: orig code needs updating. use "val" in place of "orig" in the function(i, orig).....for those who come along down the road.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass `.attr()` a function, like this:

```
$("select").attr("id", function(i, val) {
  return val + '_' + i; //i == index, val == original attribute, the id
});
```

[Scroll down a bit here to find the function overload for `.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: @ILMV - Btw this would have the effect of `row_1`, `row_2`, etc if there was 1 select per row, otherwise just adjust the selector to only grab the ones you want to re-id and you can use `i` as the count.